# Converting to DATETIME from separate date and time fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a MYSQL database in my company's workplace and the timestamps are often stored like this:

```
ModDate  |  ModTime  |  Other fields
------------------------------
20110405 |  203055   |  .....
20110506 |  214016   |  .....
```

I'm sure there was probably a valid reason for doing it at the time (developers have left), but we now mainly use SQL Server.

I've written a query to turn the `ModDate` field into standard `DATETIME`, but obviously I always get the time as `00:00:00`.

How do I get a valid `DATETIME` object from SQL Server which combines the `ModTime` and  `ModDate` field so that I get a combined correct value?  Note, I've already extracted them into a local result set and I have no intention of changing the MYSQL database (I'm simply extracting from it with an `OPENQUERY`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the table is now in SQL Server and the question has nothing to do with MySQL anymore.

```
UPDATE dbo.TableName
    SET ModDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), ModDate, 112) + ' ' 
    + STUFF(STUFF(ModTime,3,0,':'),6,0,':'));
```

If you want to make sure it's right first, just run:

```
SELECT
    ModDate, ModTime, NewModDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), ModDate, 112) + ' ' 
    + STUFF(STUFF(ModTime,3,0,':'),6,0,':'))
FROM dbo.TableName;
```

Comment: Good point, it could be either way.  Using `openquery` I could have modified the MYSQL query or the MSSQL query, ideally I wanted to avoid the MYSQL approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed looking for a MySQL solution this will fit the bill, assuming YYYYMMDD and  HHMMSS :

```
update yourtable set datetimecol =
    cast(concat(substring(moddate,1,4),'-', 
     substring(moddate,5,2),'-',
     substring(moddate,7,2),' ', 
     substring(modtime,1,2),':', 
     substring(modtime,3,2),':', 
     substring(modtime,5,2)) as datetime)
```

If you don't want to persist the data then just do a select, rather than an update, like so:

```
select cast(concat(substring(moddate,1,4),'-', 
     substring(moddate,5,2),'-',
     substring(moddate,7,2),' ', 
     substring(modtime,1,2),':', 
     substring(modtime,3,2),':', 
     substring(modtime,5,2)) as datetime) as DateTimeCol
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

...assuming that 20110405 is the 5th of April, 2011 and that you have a new column named datetimecol you could do this :

```
update yourtable set datetimecol =
    convert(datetime, substring(moddate,1,4) + '-' + 
     substring(moddate,5,2) + '-' +
     substring(moddate,7,2)+ ' ' + 
     substring(modtime,1,2) + ':' + 
     substring(modtime,3,2) + ':' + 
     substring(modtime,5,2))
```

Comment: ...sorry - I looked at the tag being SQL Server but now see in your question that you mention MYSQL; the solution here is for SQL Server per the tag

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry, I didn't make myself too clear.  I can't really update the underlying MYSQL database.  I have already extracted the date component into a DATETIME field, and the time component into a NVARCHAR field.  I need to append the time value to the date part so that I get one result...

Comment: @a12jun use DATEADD function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Why would you use NVARCHAR? Are you storing time measured in umlauts?

Answer (score 0):

To add the time part into the datetime column: You can query MySQL to return the total seconds by using TIME_TO_SEC then, use DATEADD in MSSQL

Something like this:

```
UPDATE <TABLE>
SET <datetime column> = DATEADD(second, <MYSQL_QUERY>.TOTAL_SECONDS, <datetime column>)
FROM <TABLE>
INNER JOIN <MYSQL_QUERY> ON <TABLE>.<KEY> = <MYSQL_QUERY>.<KEY>
```

The <MYSQL_QUERY> is :

```
SELECT <KEY>,TIME_TO_SEC(MOD_TIME) FROM ...
```

I'm not not sure if you can use OpenQuery in joins but I'm positive that it will work. If OpenQuery doesn't work with joins, then maybe store the query result into a temp table in MSSQL.